# count mysql values for the week and then start count again from monday?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a count query that counts how many times a user has viewed another users profile.
It currently just counts all the rows in the table, however i was wondering if there was a way in php to use a calculation that says count all rows in the table 'ptb_profile_views' from monday to sunday and then start from 0 again on the following monday and count all the values for that week and do not include any counts from the previous week, im not sure this is possible thought because it would need some time of memory aspect behind it,

the other option i was wondering is whether theres a mysql statement that i can add to say every sunday at 00:00AM delete all from ptb_profile_views and then we start fresh for monday.

can someone please help me with any sort of solution, thanks

my table looks like:

```
id   |   profile_id   |   viewed_id

1           4                 8
2           5                 6
```

mysql

```
function check_profile_views() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT profile_id) totalCOUNT FROM ptb_profile_views WHERE viewed_profile_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND profile_id!='-1'";
            $check_profile_views_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($check_profile_views_set);
            return $check_profile_views_set;        
        }
```

php

```
 <?
    $check_profile_views_set = check_profile_views();
    while ($views = mysql_fetch_array($check_profile_views_set)) {

    echo"".$views['totalCOUNT'].""; } ?>
```

Comment: You solve it by added a date/datetime column to your `ptb_profile_views` table. Then you can select them by date.

Comment: "every sunday at 00:00AM delete all from ptb_profile_views and then we start fresh for monday".  You can make a scheduled process that does this (research `schtasks` for Windows) but you should probably insert into a log table before deleting just for good measure.  Also, your SQL seems to be missing some spaces that would cause errors in execution (`...DISTINCT profile_id) totalCOUNT FROM...`)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by day-of-week, week-of-year, e.g.

```
SELECT count(*), YEAR(datefield), WEEK_OF_YEAR(datefield)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY YEAR(datefield), WEEK_OF_YEAR(datefield)
```

the deletion logic would be similar. delete all records in this year that have a week-of-year earlier than "this week", and then also delete all records from previous years:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE (YEAR(datefield) < YEAR(now()))
   OR (YEAR(datefield) = YEAR(now()) AND (WEEK_OF_YEAR(datefield) < WEEK_OF_YEAR(now()))
```

Answer (score 0):

since you mentioned you don't keep a history with datetimes for everytime someone visits a profile but just count, the only solution is to reset you counters every monday at 00:00.

You can do this with a cron job. You should be able to create one from your hosts admin panel.

Alternatively you could run the cron-page yourself manualy every monday to reset the counters.

If you would like to make things more complicated, you could have the cron-page create/update a log file where you keep the total visits.

The best solution, however, would be to rethink your database design and create a table that nicely logs each visit with the right datetime.